# How can I make my baked tortilla chips crispier?

Tags: baking, tortilla-chips

We make our own tortilla chips by sectioning up tortillas and baking them in a bit of oil and seasoning at about 375˚ F for 12 minutes. The outsides get nice and crispy but the insides of the thicker chips stay fairly soft.

I'm wondering if it would be wisest to try to increase the temperature and decrease the time or vice versa. I suppose I'm essentially dehydrating the chips so my instinct is to decrease temperature and increase time.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I would try baking them at a lower temperature *without* the oil some first, to get them partially dried out, before adding the oil and seasoning and crisping them. If the oil's on them the whole time, it'll slowly soak into the chips, instead of staying more on the outside where you want it, and depending on how much you're using, it might also be making it a little harder for water to escape.

The other main option would be to use thinner tortillas, but unless you're making them yourself, that might not be possible!